# Why am I getting a parse error for input "|" in Haskell for guards?

Tags: haskell, guard

I'm writing a code to find the median of 3 numbers but when I'm testing it, it shows a parse error for "|" in line 17. Here is the code:

```
module Median where

Median :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int

Median a b c =

    let 
        max3 a b c =

            | ((a>b) && (a>c)) = a

            | ((b>a) && (b>c)) = b

            | otherwise = c
        min3 a b c =

            | ((a<b) && (a<c)) = a

            | ((b<a) && (b<c)) = b

            | otherwise = c
    in
            (a+b+c- (max3 a b c) - (min3 a b c))
```

I've been finding the mistake over and over again and couldnt find it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Remove the `=` after `max3 a b c` and `min3 a b c`.

Comment: You may also want to rename the function `Median` to `median` as a function name must start with a lower letter.

Answer (score 1):

> Guards are indicated by pipes that follow a function's name and its
> parameters.

Source: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions

You need to remove those equal signs before the first guard.

```
example x y
   | x == y    = True
   | otherwise = False
```